# What causes 'NullPointerException' in this piece of code, reading Excel cells?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I'm using **Apache POI** for reading Excel. I've been asked to store the cells into MySQL 5.1. While I'm reading Excel cells, I've been thrown `NullPointerException`. 
This is my code snippet :

```
  int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

  for(int r = 1; r<rows; r++) {
            HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
            int cols = row.getLastCellNum();

            for(int c=0; c < cols; c++) {
                HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

                switch(cell.getColumnIndex())    {

                   case 0:
                       ....
                       ....

                   case 1:
                       ....
                       ....


                   case ...:
                       ....
                       ....

                }
            }
  }

  // Here comes the code to insert into DB
```

If anyone can identify where it arises, post asap. If I left some logic you need just ask me...

Comment: The exception arises at the line where it arises:)

Comment: Seriously tell us the line where it is thrown.

Comment: Accurately after the first line, i.e., in the for loop...

Comment: "after the first line"  is not very helpful, that only means it is not at the first line... or do you mean it is AT the first line? The StackTrace shows the exact line number, in your editor you should find that line.

Comment: when asking for a line, it is the **source line** in your code, not the line (row) of the Excel sheet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it possible that your array offset is off by one (for the row loop)?

```
for(int r = 1; r<rows; r++) {
  HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
```

instead of starting at offset 1, start at 0. This makes more sense (and matches your column loop).

In this case the result of HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r); could be null (which incidentally you should check for).

**Edit#1:**
For example:

```
  if (sheet == null) {
        return;
  }

  int rows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
  for(int r = 1; r<rows; r++) {
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
        if (row != null) {
             int cols = row.getLastCellNum();

             for(int c=0; c < cols; c++) {
                 HSSFCell cell = row.getCell(c, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);

                 if (cell != null) {
                    switch(cell.getColumnIndex())    {
                         case 0:
                         case 1:
                         case ...:

                     }
                 }
             }
      }
 }
```

If you look at [the JavaDoc](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html) this is important

```
public int getPhysicalNumberOfRows()  {
  return _rows.size();
}
```

*Returns the number of physically defined rows (**NOT** the number of rows in the sheet)*

**Edit#2:**
For the sake of further debugging please place the following try/catch around your for loop.

```
try {
     // Your for loop code here
} catch (Exception x) {
     x.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please paste a comment to this answer or update your original answer with the result of this output.

Comment: I have added an example showing how you should ensure the returned objects are not null. Of more importance is that the Javadoc for the sheet object you are using indicates that just because getPhysicalNumberOfRows returns 10 rows does not mean there is 10 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I don't explain your NPE, but propose you an other way to iterate over workbook, have you tried this ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
    final Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
    final Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    if (rows.hasNext()) {
       final Row header = rows.next();
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess cell may be null, but you should use debugger to find out the exception place.

Answer (score 0):

From the code given, either `sheet`, `row` or `cell` will be null. The exception stack trace itself should tell you exactly what line is causing the problem.

First thoughts are that you're getting the physical number of rows in the sheet but `getRow()` gets you a logical row. You may want to look into using `getFirstRowNum()` and `getLastRowNum()` which appear to return *logical* rows.

But that just my thoughts. More information is needed before I can say for sure.

---

To get a stack trace given your exception `npe`, use:

```
npe.printStackTrace();
```

or:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw, true);
npe.printStackTrace(pw);
pw.flush();
sw.flush();
// sw.toString(); to get a string for putting into a text box or something else.
```

Comment: I'm getting expected results upto the first line, starts with 'int rows'. But after that only I'm getting the NullPointerException..

Comment: If the "int rows" line throws the exception, then sheet is null.

Comment: @ven, how are you setting sheet?

Comment: I said 'int rows' returns what it has to return... After that line of code only I've this Exception...

Comment: @ven, you need to post the entire copy of the exception.

Comment: I've caught the exception in the JOptionPane. It just shows "java.lang.NullPointerException'. I've caught it as 'npe'. I've tried getCause() and getMessage() but both returns just 'null'

Comment: @ven, see the update on how to get the full stack trace. You need to examine that to find out where the problem lies.